# Unable to create dataflow job via dataflow console:Found unexpected parameters: ['key' (perhaps you meant 'region')]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataflow

i have created a dataflow job which accepts as input a parameter called 'key'.
I have created the template with the following command

```
--template_location=gs://mm_dataflow_bucket/templates/marketstats_template
--staging_location=gs://mm_dataflow_bucket/staging --setup ./setup.py --key <my key>
```

I have then created the following metadata

```
{
  "description": "An example pipeline that collect market stats.",
  "name": "Market Stats",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "key",
      "helpText": "IEX API",
      "label": "IEXAPI"
    }
  ]
}
```

However when i attempt to create the dataflow job via console i am getting back this

```
(cf16dcf1ac642eb2): The workflow could not be created. Causes: (cf16dcf1ac64261b): Found unexpected parameters: ['key' (perhaps you meant 'region')]
```

This seems to have happened since this week,as i have created templates in the past week which all accepts parameters and they all worked fine
Anyone could asssist?

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

My custom args class was extending the wrong class. I was extending `StandardOptions` where as I should have been extending `PipelineOptions`

Their arg parsing code seems like a giant confusing hack and I am very angry by it from loosing 6 hours of my life.

### More details:

I had

```
class ReviewProcessingOptions(StandardOptions):

  @classmethod   def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):

    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--reports',
        dest='reports',
        help='report ids that are to be processed (comma separated)',
    )
    ...
```

where I should have had

```
class ReviewProcessingOptions(PipelineOptions):

  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):

    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
        '--reports',
        dest='reports',
        help='report ids that are to be processed (comma separated)',
    )
    ...
```

I was using the `runner` param in my start script to do some logic and needed access to it. Thinking "ahh StandardOptions is a child of PipelineOptions i should be fine", I extended that class. But it does not work.

First thing to check is template file that is uploaded to storage (its a giant file of json). It should have the variables defined. The variables only started showing up once I extended PipelineOptions.

Here is a snippet from mine

```
{"key": "reports", "namespace": "apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.GoogleCloudOptions", "type": "STRING", "value": "RuntimeValueProvider(option: reports, type: str, default_value: None)"}
```

Answer (score -2):

I understand that you are using "gcloud dataflow jobs run" command.

Here are all the flags allowed for the command.[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run).

There aren't any flags that resemble what you specified as "key". Can you please provide further explanation of which kind of parameters do you want to include in that flag